# Installing OpenGL 4.0 on OSX

Tags: macos, opengl, opengl-4

I wanted to know if there is any possible way to update to the latest version of OpenGL on OSX. Is there any way to run programs that make use of OpenGL 4.0 calls on OSX?

Comment: OpenGL 4.0 on *a Mac* or *on OSX*?

Comment: OSX. I should have been clearer. My current version is 10.8.3

Comment: 4.0 is not "the latest version of OpenGL". That's 4.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait for Apple and/or [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/) to support 4.0.

Comment: OS X Mavericks is the solution!